# Copy the content of a div into another div

Tags: javascript, html

I have two divs on my website. They both share the same css properties, but one of them holds 24 other divs. I want all of these 24 divs to be copied into the other div.
This is how it looks like:

```
<div id="mydiv1">
    <div id="div1">
    </div>
    </div id="div2>
    </div>
    //and all the way up to div 24.
</div>

<div id="mydiv2">
</div>
```

I want all of the 24 divs within mydiv1 to be copied into mydiv2 when the page loads.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Firstly we are assigning divs into variables (optional)

```
var firstDivContent = document.getElementById('mydiv1');
var secondDivContent = document.getElementById('mydiv2');
```

Now just assign mydiv1's content to mydiv2.

```
secondDivContent.innerHTML = firstDivContent.innerHTML;
```

**DEMO**
http://jsfiddle.net/GCn8j/

**COMPLETE CODE**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function copyDiv(){
      var firstDivContent = document.getElementById('mydiv1');
      var secondDivContent = document.getElementById('mydiv2');
      secondDivContent.innerHTML = firstDivContent.innerHTML;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="copyDiv();">
  <div id="mydiv1">
      <div id="div1">
      </div>
      <div id="div2">
      </div>
  </div>

  <div id="mydiv2">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't forget var firstDivContent and so on. Exposing the variables to the global scope is bad practice

Comment: This wont actually work, `innerHTML` returns a string not a reference to the property of the element

Comment: @EricHerlitz Thanks for warning me about `var`s.

Comment: Worked just like I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: How about this, where I also want to copy properties and properties of children? http://jsfiddle.net/GCn8j/2/

Comment: @Luc You can do it by assigning one div's style propery to another. Please check this modified example of yours: http://jsfiddle.net/moonlife/LyLhxnkk/

Comment: @AycanYaşıt So by copying all properties individually... is there no better way?

Comment: @Luc A better way would be to define styles in Css, and to assign this class name to your target div.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event of jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.div1').html(jQuery("#div2").html());
}
```

Also a working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UKBxH/39/).

Answer (score 2):

```
var divs = document.getElementById('mydiv1').innerHTML;

document.getElementById('mydiv2').innerHTML= divs;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one in 2022.

```
let clonedDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv').cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(clonedDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative in jquery You can use `clone` and put it in your target div. Example:

```
$('#mydiv1').clone().appendTo('#mydiv2');
```

Copy `#mydiv1` into `#mydiv2`