# How to clone the contents of a div into another div with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to clone the images of the div `leftSide` into the div `rightSide`. On each click on the body the images on the left div should be cloned into the right div. But I can't get the result with the code I'm doing. Is there any mistake in my code? I want to use JavaScript.

Here's my code:

```
        var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");  
        var width = 500; var height = 500;
        top_position = 0; var left_position = 0,
        var numberOfFaces = 5;
        var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
        var leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
        document.getElementById("rightSide").appendChild(leftSideImages);


            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            createElement(i);   
            numberOfFaces += 5;

        function createElement() {
            var image = document.createElement('img');
            image.src = "smile.png";
            image.style.position = 'absolute';
            image.style.top = top_position + "px";
            image.style.left = left_position + "px";
            theLeftSide.appendChild(image);
            top_position = Math.random() *   500 ;
            left_position = Math.random() *  500 ;
```

Comment: Could you share the div code as well? Or you could simply try this if you have second div on page. document.getElementById(''SecondDv").innerHTML = document.getElementById(''FirstDv").innerHTML; This will copy whatever is there in FirstDiv to Second.

Comment: Could you please supply more details about what you have and what you want to do?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this because jQuery solutions do _not_ answer a question that specifically asks for Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example that clones an `HTMLElement` in vanilla javascript:

> additional information can be found in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

```js
function CloneCtrl() {
  'use strict';
  var self = this;
  
  self.source = document.querySelector('.source');
  self.target = document.querySelector('.target');
  
  self.cloneSource = function(event) {
    var clone = self.source.cloneNode(true);
    
    self.target.appendChild(clone);
  }
  
  document
    .getElementById('cloneBtn')
    .addEventListener('click', self.cloneSource)
  ;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', CloneCtrl);
```

```css
.source {
  background: lightseagreen;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.target {
  border: 1px solid lightcoral;
  min-height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div><button id="cloneBtn">Clone Source</button></div>
<div class="source">SOURCE</div>
<hr>
<div class="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, you can do it kike that:

```
$('#div2').html($('#div1').html());
```

which is found from this question: [Copy the content of a div into another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173101/copy-the-content-of-a-div-into-another-div).

---

You don't actually provide many details, thus the best I can post, hope it helps!!

Comment: keep in mind the OP said in JavaScript, might as well provide the alternative

Comment: that's actually JQuery, but it's also JS I'm just saying since the OP seems like someone confused about easy coding

Comment: Oh @AGE, I see, I updated, do you like my answer now?:)

Answer (score 1):

you could simply try this if you have second div on page.

```
 document.getElementById("SecondDv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("FirstDv").innerHTML;
```

This will copy whatever is there in FirstDiv to Second. lmk if it works.