# Using jquery to have one html element point to another

Tags: html, jquery, element

I am new to jquery and was wondering how I can point one html element equal to another. I want to make it so that whenever something in the h2 tag changes, the text within the p tags will copy the change. Below is how my tags are set up within the class fc-center.

```
 var title = $('div.fc-center h2').text();
 $('.fc-center').append('<p>'+'' +'</p>');
```

with the html looking something like

```
<div class = 'fc-center'>
<h2> text text</h2>
<p> </p>
</div>
```

essentially what I want to do is something like this :

```
$('div.fc-center p').equalto $('div.fc-center h2')
```

But I am not quite sure how to go about it

Comment: To do it once: [Copy the content of a div into another div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20173101/215552). Think really hard whether you want to have the contents copy automatically. Instead, consider changing the functions that change the `h2` so that they also change the `p`, or so that they call the function that copies the content from the `h2` to the `p`. Having it done automatically can slow your page down.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the function that changes h2

Comment: Use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Answer (score 1):

I propose this solution:

```
 var title = $('.fc-center').find('h2').text();
 
 var elementsP=$('.fc-center').find('p');
 
 if (elementsP.length > 0) {
 
   $.each(elementsP, function(i, val) {
   
    $(this).empty().html(title);
    
   });
   
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/julian9319/grc0y6qf/1/

Comment: I see the intent behind this solution however it does not quite work as for the p tag to be updated, the page must be refreshed. I want the p tag to be updated as the h2 tag changes, also im quite confused by the if statement part if you dont mind explaining